# Not able to run the Eureka Client Application after Spring Boot migration from 1.5.x to 2.1.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

As part of Spring Boot migration from 1.5.12 to 2.1.14. We have to migrate Spring Cloud dependncies as well. So for this I have Spring cloud version
as 'Greenwich.SR4'(supported version for Spring Boot 2.1.x) from 'Dalston.SR4'.

compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:1.3.5.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.3.5.RELEASE")
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:1.4.6.RELEASE") {
force = true
}

Here I have Eureka server and Eureka Client apps (Gateway Zuul), I have seen Eureka server is started but client is not able to registered. but before migration it was
working fine. Even I have usesd the following dependencies from Netflix but nothing has worked out.

```
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
//compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul")
```

I'm getting the following error when I started running the ZuulGateWay Application which acts as Eureka client:

Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server

WARN  zuul   c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient  2020-07-01 13:34:25.920  Request execution failure with status code 401; retrying on another server if available
GGXDV  ERROR  zuul   c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient  2020-07-01 13:34:25.924  DiscoveryClient_ZUUL/WGA10015LDITEGG.uswin.ad.com:zuul:8092 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1069)

I'm not able to get what is the problem after migration, while running the Eureka server, I don't see any issue but getting the above error when I run Eureka Client.

But still I have a doubt whether we have a problem in Eureka Server or Eureka Client.

Can any one suggest me how to solve this issue?

Comment: "failure with status code 401". You have secured eureka and the client isn't passing the right credentials? You haven't shown your configuration so it is hard to know.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb, I was using spring security oauth2 earlier but in the latest version Authorization server support was removed right. that's why I have commented out security related classes. May be I may not knwo where disable the security in the configuration files. Could you plz point out?